# Get access to the request (HttpRequestMessage) in a WebAPI constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to get access to the request (of type HttpRequestMessage) in the constructor of an ApiController. Unfortunately, at this stage of the object creation, the Request property isn't initialized yet and the HttpContext.Current.Request contains the request in the "old" class format (HttpRequest).

Is there a way to access the HttpRequestMessage during controller construction ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to execute common logic for all actions? If that's the case, Action filters are more suitable for that.

Comment: No. I want to extract informations from the http header to initialize some properties of my controller.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to accomplish, there may be a better way to do it?

Comment: @Mike Sheehan : No unfortunately, I had to change my design. I'll be glad if someone find a solution to this for future projects.

Answer (score 3):

While you cannot access the Http Request in the constructor, it can be accessed using the [Initialize method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt134821(v=vs.118)). Here is the code to access the Http Request object via this method

```cs
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
   var request = controllerContext.Request;

   base.Initialize(controllerContext);
}
```

I ran into a situation where I needed JWT token before any function is called and this solution worked well for me.

**Note**: Make sure to include `base.Initialize(controllerContext);` to avoid runtime errors.

Comment: I was trying to get access to one of the Request properties in the constructor for my controller. With this tip, I was able to access that property in my override for the Initialize method and all is well.